# Lack of timestamps in some entities in OneNote

Tags: http, http-caching, onenote-api

I am currently working on a mobile application that uses the OneNote REST API that sometimes have really enormous ping, so the cache implementation is one of the most important aspects with impact on my application's performance. But, for the purpose of implementing traffic-effective cache with data staying up-to-date the timestamp is needed for ***all of the entities*** that are not stable or their amount can grow (practically any entities fit these conditions). So, The question is whether the timestamp (e.g. lastModified, lastModifiedTime etc.) properties do not present in some entities, for example - permissions, principal objects or they are just hidden and it is possible to use the $expand to get them.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see a timestamp in one of the entities, then the entity does not have it.

Adding timestamp for some of this entities can be challenging for us, as they the datastore we're using might not have it, but I encourage you to ask for suggestions in our uservoice page.

https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/245490-onenote-developer-apis